# print Data to <ul> tag using JAVASCRIPT JQUERY in web forms asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I have this function to get data from a database Using JSON AJAX

```
function BindMembers() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/P.asmx/p1",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var list = "";
                $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                    list += "<li class='text-secondary p-1'><a class='btn-link text-secondary'><b>" + item.Id + "</b>" + ", " + "<span class='font-italic'><small>" + item.Id + "</small></span><small><a href='#' Onclick='Delete(" + item.Id + ")'> <i class='float-right far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></small></a>" + "</li>";
                });
                $("#list").html(list);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this my Html Code i need to get data from this function and display into this list

```
<ul id="list">
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you show op of `data` in your ajax call ?

Comment: @Swati i show the data when i am click in inspect network

Comment: add that op in your question as well .

Comment: @Swati no ajax it's working my problem how to diplay this data to list

Comment: no i mean to say add output of `data` which you are getting in success function in your asked question ..because your current code looks ok .. i think you have problem while printing values .

Comment: @Swati Yes that's my problem

Comment: Please update question with detail of `data`.